# pass fields when applying ST_VoronoiPolygons and clip output

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I am performing Voronoi Polygons of layer1 (points, "geometry field" = geometry) to create layer2 (polygons, "geometry field" = geom). The following command works

```
CREATE TABLE layer2
AS WITH voronoi (vor)
AS (SELECT ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geometry)))
FROM layer1) SELECT (vor).path, (vor).geom FROM voronoi
```

results looks like that (layer1 = green points, layer2 = black polygons, layer3 = red polygon)

[Image of the 3 layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixLsy.png)

however, none of the field from layer1 are maintained in layer2. I would like I would like to pass field1 and field2 from layer1 to layer2.

Additionally, I would like to clip the result within the boundary of a single polygon layer (layer3).

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by (to pass field1 and filed2 from layer1 to layer2)?. And (does layer 3) represents the boundary of the points?

Comment: I think I used the wrong term. I should replace layer by table, and field by column. 
I want to retrieve the information from field1 and field2 (or column1 and column2) included in Layer1 (or Table1) in Layer2 (or Table2).
Notice that with the Voronoi, each item (point) from Layer1 corresponds to an item to Layer2.

Comment: layer 3 is a polygon use to clip final output.

Answer (score 2):

No Answer so far, but I found a solution to my problem that I can share.

It is not very fancy but it works. I apply a spatial join between layer1 and Layer2. Since there is only 1 point inside each polygon (by definition of the Voronoi), it works perfectly.

Perform the voronoi (same as previous post)

```
CREATE TABLE layerTMP
AS WITH voronoi (vor)
AS (SELECT ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(geometry)))
FROM layer1) SELECT (vor).path, (vor).geom FROM voronoi;
```

do the spatial join

```
CREATE TABLE layer2 AS
SELECT layer1.*,layerTMP.*
FROM layerTMP, layer1
WHERE ST_Contains( layerTMP.geom, layer1.geometry);
```

remove the "geometry" column of the point layer (layer1) and the "path" column from voronoi

```
ALTER TABLE layer2 DROP geometry;
ALTER TABLE WeatherAgri4CastID_grid DROP "path";
```

hope this will help other users ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This query will cut your voronoi using a cookie cutter of larger polygons. In this example I used country boundaries.

The index is not necessary but recommended;

```sql
create table voronoi_output as
SELECT
    geom as polygon_wkb_geometry,
    points.name,
    points.code
FROM (
     SELECT
         st_intersection((ST_Dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(points.wkb_geometry)))).geom, cookie_cutter.wkb_geometry) as geom
        FROM table1 as points, table2 as cookie_cutter
           where st_contains(cookie_cutter.wkb_geometry, points.wkb_geometry)
           group by cookie_cutter.wkb_geometry
    ) as voronoi,
      table1 as points
WHERE st_within(points.wkb_geometry, voronoi.geom);
create index vornoi on voronoi_output using GIST(polygon_wkb_geometry);
```

[image]